# React-Redux mapStateToProps doesn't trigger when state changes

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning Redux state management and got stuck with an issue. The mapStateToProps within a component is not triggered when the state changes. Gone through a lot of blogs, couldn't able to figure out the problem. 
The store seems to update properly, as the "subscribe" method on store prints new changes. Attached screenshot as well.

Actions.js

```
export const GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS = "GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS";
export const GET_ITEMS_FAILURE = "GET_ITEMS_FAILURE";
export const getItemsSuccess = (items) => ({
    type: GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS, payload: items
});
export const getItemsFailure = (error) => ({
    type: GET_ITEMS_FAILURE, error: error
}); 
export function getItems(dispatch) {
    return dispatch => {
    fetch(myList)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            if(res.error) {
                throw(res.error);
            }
            store.dispatch(getItemsSuccess(res));
            return res;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            store.dispatch(getItemsFailure(error));
        })
   }
}
```

Reducer

```
let initialState = {items: [], error: null}
function GetItemsReducer (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS: 
           return Object.assign({}, state, {pending: false, items: action.payload});
       case GET_ITEMS_FAILURE:
           return Object.assign({}, state, {pending: false, error: action.error});
       default: 
           return state; 
    }
}
export default const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    GetItemsReducer: GetItemsReducer
});
```

Store

```
const mystore = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, promise));
mystore.subscribe(() => console.log("State Changed;", mystore.getState()));
```

Component

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchItems();
    }
    render() {
       return (
          <div>{this.props.items.length}</div>
       )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   console.log('mapStateToProps ----------> ', state);
   return {
      items: state.GetItemsReducer.items,
      error: state.GetItemsReducer.error
   }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
       fetchItems: bindActionCreators(getItems, dispatch)
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Main

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return (
          <Provider store={mystore}>
             <Home />
          </Provider>
       )
   }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you saying `var mapStateToProps = function mapStateToProps(state)` instead of just `function mapStateToProps(state)`

Comment: JohnSnow, I with that and arrow function too, no luck

Comment: the actions creator, `getItemsSuccess`, `items` is probably undefined, isn't?

Comment: This is incorrect as well `items: state.GetItemsReducer.items,` you don't call the reducer in map state to props, the result of the reducer updates the global state which is accessible in `mapStateToProps` so change it to `items: state.items`

Comment: Federkun, apologies, I manually typed the code, missed it. corrected now. To your question, they're not undefined.

Comment: same for `store.dispatch(getItemsSuccess(res));`; is that correct? do you have access to store?

Comment: JohnSnow, trying your suggestion. An exception is thrown.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined for {this.props.items.length}

My state looks like below in console.
{GetItemsReducer: {…}}
GetItemsReducer:
error: "null"
items: []
pending: false
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: Federkun, Please see the attached screenshot of the store logs. Data is updated (7 items in array) in the store post API call, but mapsStateToProps is not triggered.

Comment: Do `Todo` and `actionType` refer to the same constant? In your actions you're namespacing it as `Todo` and in your reducer it is `actionType`. If you fail every condition in your case statement, it's going to return the original state, and not trigger any updates

Comment: Yes, Andrew. Both are same, just imported into different files with different names. Corrected here to avoid confusion.

Comment: Meanwhile, here is the library version that I used.

  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "mocha": "^6.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.4.1",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.2",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sinon": "^7.3.2"
  },

Comment: It works correctly when I create an minimal example with your code https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-tu-nbpcc

Comment: Tien Duong, oh, nice. Let me try using the same library versions that you used in your sample. Will get back soon

Comment: yay! Changing the "react-redux" & "redux" version as per your sample works. Great thanks, @TienDuong.
Thanks, everyone for helping me out.